# Mercurial reported error number 255: abort: Resource busy

Tags: macos, networking, mercurial, locking, intranet

Using MacHG I get this message:

"Mercurial reported error number 255:abort: Resource busy"

I'm trying to push changes across a local network from my mac to a SMB mounted shared directory. It was working earlier today for 2 pushes and a clone.

I have read all the forums about lock files and symlinks and that SMB supports symlinks for the file locking to work.

Also there are no .hg/store/lock or .hg/wlock files for me to delete to resolve the locking scenario.

**EDIT:** After trying CIFS as the protocol for mounting the share it would appear CIFS is now reporting the same issue/error message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After repeating tests of:

- Switching from SMB to CIFS
- performing a verify on each repository.
- Closing MacHG on all computers involved.
- Closing XCode on all computers involved
- Restarting all computers involved

It would seem the only solution that was consistent is to **NOT map to a networked share folder**...

http://hginit.com/02.html

The above link is a really great guide on getting a simple intranet share happening.

You'll need to edit the `.hg/hgrc` file so that it includes the following lines:

```
[web]
push_ssl=False
allow_push=*
```

Then in our situation we created a startup script (batch file for windows in our case) for when the server turned on to make sure it performed the following:

```
taskkill /f /im hg.exe /t

cd pathtorepository\MyProject
hg serve -d -p <portnumber1>

cd pathtosecondproject\MySecondProject
hg serve -d -p <portnumber2>
```

Visit the mercurial wiki or search SO for more details on setting up hg serve if you requre secure connections and authentication

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/hgserve